# Django Custome Templatetags dont work in my production setup

Tags: django, django-templates

I have my project structure as shown below

```
project
  - utils
    - templatetags
      __init__.py
      date_format.py
```

date_format.py has 2 filters, DEFAULT_FORMAT, CUSTOM_FORMAT

date_format.py

```
@register.filter(name='DEFAULT_FORMAT', expects_localtime=True)
def default_format(value):
  logger.info("Value")
  logger.info(value)
  if value is None or value == "":
    return ""

  if isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, unicode):
    return value

  return get_date_string(value)


@register.filter(name='CUSTOM_FORMAT', expects_localtime=True)
def custom_format(value, date_format):
  logger.info("Custom format")
  if value is None or value == "":
    return ""

  if isinstance(value, str) or isinstance(value, unicode):
    return value

  return get_formatted_string(value, date_format)
```

I have a template which uses both DEFAULT_FORMAT and CUSTOM_FORMAT, I am also importing the tags using {% load date_format %}

This works fine in my local environment, but strangely doesn't work in my production, It says Invalid filter: CUSTOM_FORMAT.

Point to note here is DEFAULT_FORMAT comes ahead of CUSTOM_FORMAT in this template and yet one of the loads fine while the other throws error.

Can someone point me in the right direction to sort this out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add date_format.py codebase.

Comment: @Pushplata I have added the code to my question, please have a look

Comment: Please share complete date_format.py and also is utils is your django app.